# React: What happens on consecutive renders where a list shuffles?

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations, reactjs

I am trying to create a list which shuffles randomly with some animation.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wcpLLg4/) for it where I have used `key` prop to identify each child.

http://jsfiddle.net/1wcpLLg4/

```
var ListAnimate = React.createClass({
    list: [
        {id: 1, caption: "Hello"},
        {id: 2, caption: "There"},
        {id: 3, caption: "Whatsup"},
        {id: 4, caption: "Sanket"},
        {id: 5, caption: "Sahu"},
    ],
    shuffle: function() {
        this.list.shuffle(); // Shuffles array!
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.shuffle}>Shuffle</button>
            <ul>
                {this.list.map(function(el, i){
                    return <li key={el.id} style={ {top: (i*60)+'px'} }>{el.caption} {el.id}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<ListAnimate />, document.body);
```

From the [React docs about Dynamic Children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children), it states that `key` prop is used in order to identify the elements in an array during successive renders. So, that the items which are just re-ordered must not unmount and mount to new position rather they should just be re-positioned but the does not seem to be happening in the fiddle, where the Nodes at the top of the list are always being unmounted and being mounted at a different position.

But for the elements at the bottom seems to be working well with animation.

Comment: You need to click Fork in the fiddle when you're done making changes.  The link just goes to the hello world fiddle.  Also you need to include the code from your fiddle in the question, in case jsfiddle goes away.

Comment: Sorry, updated it now! (y)

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that for the kind of animation you are looking for, you need to always keep the DOM in the same order and only update their position in the render function of your component.

I modified your first fiddle using this strategy: http://jsfiddle.net/0maphg47/1/

```
render: function() {
    // create a sorted version of the list to render the DOM
    var sortedCopy = this.state.list.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });

    return <div>
        <button onClick={this.shuffle}>Shuffle</button>
        <ul>
            {sortedCopy.map(function(el, i) {
                // find the position of the element in the shuffled list
                // which gives the position the element must be
                var pos = this.state.list.indexOf(el);
                return <li key={el.id} style={ {top: (pos*60)+'px'} }>
                    {el.caption} {el.id}
                </li>;
            }, this)}
        </ul>
    </div>;
}
```

There is still room for improvement but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and the fiddle! This works well but my solution should also work. It looks like there is a problem with React's render function (as mentioned in the comment of the other answer)

Comment: Have you read this article about React's algorithm? In the last section, "[...] you can express the fact that a sub-tree has been moved amongst its siblings, but you cannot tell that it has moved somewhere else." http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: Thanks!  You helped me with a separate problem I was having with copying JS arrays, `.slice()` was the key piece I needed in `this.state.list.slice().sort...`

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fiddle to show that `li` elements are not actually being mounted / unmounted.

http://jsfiddle.net/jq9p7hnd/

I have converted `li` element to `MyLi` element and logged messages when the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` functions are called. Only the `componentDidMount` callbacks are called during the first render and none of them are called after shuffle:

```
var MyLi = React.createClass({


    componentDidMount : function(){
        console.log("MyLi component did mount.");
    },

    componentWillUnmount : function(){
        console.log("MyLi component will unmount.");
    },

    render : function(){

        return <li {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</li>

    }
});

var ListAnimate = React.createClass({
    list: [
        {id: 1, caption: "Hello"},
        {id: 2, caption: "There"},
        {id: 3, caption: "Whatsup"},
        {id: 4, caption: "Sanket"},
        {id: 5, caption: "Sahu"},
    ],
    shuffle: function() {
        this.list.shuffle();
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.shuffle}>Shuffle</button>
            <ul>
                {this.list.map(function(el, i){
                    return <MyLi key={el.id} style={ {top: (i*60)+'px'} }>{el.caption} {el.id}</MyLi>;
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
});
window.React = React; 
React.render(<ListAnimate />, document.body);









Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  var i = this.length, j, temp;
  if ( i == 0 ) return this;
  while ( --i ) {
     j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     temp = this[i];
     this[i] = this[j];
     this[j] = temp;
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Good debug, but what could be wrong with the positioning? That's not a CSS issues, I checked in Inspector Elements panel.

Comment: I think React reorders the actual DOM elements (it does not throw away existing DOM elements and React class instances and create new ones) and updates the `top` style attribute of them.

Comment: If it re-orders the existing DOM, then why do only those elements are animating which are moving from bottom to top and does not work with the elements from top to bottom? In Google Chrome's debugger, it loses the selected element in Elements panel if it moves down but the selection remains for the elements which rise up.

Comment: I see your point. I cant give an authoritative answer for that but I think it makes sense if re-ordering algorithm works that way. "Move elements from bottom to top to accomplish the given ordering." But probably more complex than that.

Comment: Currently reordering doesn't always work, it's an implementation detail mostly.  There's an issue for it that I can't seem to find right now, but it explains the situation in more detail.  If you find it, comment on it so they know it's important to you.